# Is it possible to access gmail anonymous profile for a logged in user?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, tags, pixel, google-tag-manager

If user visits my website from a desktop then an hour later visits the site from her cell phone, I need to track to see it was the same user. One way to do this is I need to somehow anonymously read the unique id that is attached to the google profile of the signed in user and pass it to my google tag so Google Universal Analytics can track user sessions across multiple platforms.

Can you please suggest the best way to do this, I might even not need to access profile id for this as I know this might be a little hacky.

*Users will not sign into my website so I can't use my own authentication mechanism.*

Comment: what if the user doesn't use google?

Comment: I guess I should be fine with only if user has a signed in google account, maybe I extend the same method to facebook and tweeter if it worked for google.

Comment: the problem is that those setups use cookies, cookies belonging to the provider, and cookies cannot be read from other domains. in short, you can't really do this without cooperation from the provider, and the only cooperation they offer (afaik) is heavy-handed user interaction like oauth.

Comment: Yeah I agree, that's why I wasn't sure if this is really possible or not

Comment: Could you explain the wider scenario why you want to do this? Google already have solutions in place to track cross-device conversions, which you might be able to use, depending on your particular requirement.

Comment: We are using a pixel/tag that tracks (well needs to track) cross device conversions, any kind of suggestion for doing this is highly appreciated :-)

Comment: Our visitors are coming from a variety of devices and we don't have authentication or any sort of tracking users, but we need to implement this mechanism so I'm not really sure how we can achieve this